# SQL derived table results in unknown column

Tags: sql, mysql-error-1054, derived-table

```
+------------------+        +------------------+    
| object           |        | example          |
+------------------+        +------------------+    
| id               |        | id               |    
| table_name       |        | ...              |    
| ref_id           |        |                  |    
+------------------+        +------------------+    

object  [ id = 5, table_name = example, ref_id = 2]
example [ id = 2 ]
```

I have a table which can represent a group of objects originating from a number of different tables.
These objects all have an `id`, referenced by `object.ref_id`.

I am trying to select the original object (from the table referenced by `object.table_name`) by `object.id`. For this, I am trying to use the following SQL query. Though this results in `#1054 - Unknown column 'entity.id' in 'where clause'`.

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    (
        SELECT  table_name
        FROM    object 
        WHERE   id = 5) AS entity
WHERE   entity.id = (
        SELECT  ref_id
        FROM    object 
        WHERE   id = 5)
```

What am I doing wrong?

**CASE EXAMPLE**

```
SELECT * 
FROM example 
WHERE id = (
    SELECT  ref_id
    FROM    object 
    WHERE   id = 5 )
```

Although, for my case the FROM clause is not as easy as in the example, since this value is normally derived from `object.table_name`.

**UPDATE WITH TOMBOM'S APPROACH**

Using the solution from Tombom results in an error, for the sake of testing I have replaced the variables in the CONCAT function.

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', 'example', ' WHERE id = ', '1');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

> #1243 - Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't tell MySQL that the result of a (sub)query is a table name this way. You'd have to build a dynamic statement with the result.

```
SELECT @tableName:=table_name, @refId:=ref_id FROM object WHERE id = 5 LIMIT 1;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', @tableName, ' WHERE id = ', @refId);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

UPDATE: Please have a try with a stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE procName(IN my_id INT)
BEGIN
SELECT @tableName:=table_name, @refId:=ref_id FROM object WHERE id = my_id LIMIT 1;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', @tableName, ' WHERE id = ', @refId);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then execute the stored procedure with

```
CALL procName(5);
```

Comment: So, any feedback? Is it not, what you're looking for?

Comment: I am experiencing some problems. Will post an update in the question since it won't be very readable inside this comment.

Comment: Though your solution seems valid according to MySQL documentation. I don't know what is causing my error though.

Comment: How are you executing the statements? Are you using phpMyadmin or any other GUI, console or in a PHP script or whatever?

Comment: This will be executed with PHP, however for testing purposes I am executing this directly with phpmyadmin. Version information: 3.5.2.2, latest stable version: 3.5.7

Comment: I never stumbled over this error before, can you please try with my updated answer?

Comment: Weird indeed, worked without procedure, too, when I tried it again. Seems to be a bug?

Comment: You mean in PHPMyAdmin or MySQL?

Comment: `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE` also results in an error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax. `CREATE PROCEDURE` works fine though.

Comment: `DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS procName; CREATE PROCEDURE...`  CREATE OR REPLACE does not exist

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered exactly the same problem recently. When I deleted the last line `DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;` everything started working.