# Executing mysql query in php to get columns and row

Tags: php, mysql

I need to display attendance of all employees based on the selected dates from a single table.

This is my MySQL query:

```
        SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
          'max(CASE WHEN ca.Date = ''',
          date_format(Date, '%Y-%m-%d'),
          ''' THEN coalesce(p.Out_time) END) AS `',
          date_format(Date, '%Y-%m-%d'), '`'
        )
      ) INTO @sql
    FROM attendance
    where Date>='2015-04-27'
      and Date <= '2015-04-30';

    SET @sql 
      = CONCAT('SELECT ca.User_name,
                  ca.User_id,
                  ', @sql, ' 
                from
                (
                  select c.Date, a.User_name, a.User_id
                  from attendance c
                  cross join attendance a
                ) ca
                left join attendance p
                  on ca.User_id = p.User_id
                  and ca.Date = p.Date
                where ca.Date>=''2015-04-27''
                  and ca.Date <= ''2015-04-30''
                group by ca.User_name, ca.User_id
                order by ca.User_id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

It is executing fine in MySQL (it displays the result) but while executing in php it does not display anything,

```
$qqq=mysql_query($sss);

while($rrr=mysql_fetch_array($qqq))
{
echo $rrr; 
}
```

It is throwing these warnings:

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in D:\Xampp\htdocs\php\temp.php on line 118

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in D:\Xampp\htdocs\php\temp.php on line 119
```

My table structure is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `attendance` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `User_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `User_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `In_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `Out_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `Time_diff` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Id_UNIQUE` (`Id`)
)
```

Comment: post your php code that is not working

Comment: $sss=" MySQL query given above";$qqq=mysql_query($sss);

while($rrr=mysql_fetch_array($qqq))
{
echo $rrr; 
}

Comment: Please post the declaration of $sss, which is where the problem appears to lie.

Comment: Actually I am not getting any idea how to execute this query in php,

Comment: [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) does not support multiple queries (ie. nothing after 1st semi-colon `;`).  Update to `mysqli` and use [`mysqli_multi_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Comment: Or change the query into a single one.

Comment: I think better solution would be to create a mysql procedure for the same and then call that procedure using the mysql_query function

Comment: how can I change the query into single line

Comment: If it was me, I'd start again, with proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) and a desired result.

Answer (score -2):

You can create procedure and execute it through php.

For more information and implementation refer link: [Prepare Statement Execution Using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336989/sql-derived-table-results-in-unknown-column)

Hope this will help you.